Unable to add apply plugin: "realm-android" in new Gradle version catalog
I'm trying to add realm to my project and I'm using realm java SDK version.
I can add the classpath in the project-level gradle but I can't add the id "realm-android" in the app-level gradle plugin.
I don't know how to add this to the version catalog.
Note: I am using Kotlin Gradle, not Groovy and the Android Gradle plugin version is 8.3.1
I added classpath in project level gradle by like this
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
realmGradlePlugin = "10.17.0"

[libraries]
realm-gradle-plugin = { module = "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "realmGradlePlugin" }

And I want to add an apply plugin: "realm-android" in the app level gradle. Hope I will get some assistance here.

I had the same issue recently and ended up declaring the classpath in the .toml file and the plugin ID directly in the module. Like this:
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
realm = "10.18.0"

[libraries]
realm-gradle-plugin = { module = "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "realm" }

build.gradle.kts
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.realm.gradle.plugin)
    }
}

module/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("realm-android")
}

In the MongoDB developer community you can follow this thread: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-use-realm-gradle-plugin-with-version-catalogs/267376

Thanks for your answer @Andre sousa I already solved it. In my case, I just changed the order of the plugin id in Gradle also posted here.

I solved this issue myself. In my case, I just changed the order of plugin id in app level gradle like this and it works but I don't know reason.
Before :
   id("realm-android")
   kotlin("kept")
After :
   kotlin("kapt")
   id("realm-android") // below kapt realm will work

And in my project-level gradle(for reference)
[versions]
realmGradlePlugin = "10.17.0"

[libraries]
realm-gradle-plugin = { module = "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "realmGradlePlugin" }


Realm's Java SDK does not support version catalogs (or, specifically, the newer plugins { style of definition). This is supported by their documentation, although the Kotlin SDK does support it.

The Java SDK does not yet support the Gradle Plugin syntax. Fortunately, you can still add the SDK to projects that use this syntax.

As others have stated, this means the plugin will need to be defined differently. For example, my setup:
libs.versions.toml:
[versions]
realm = '10.15.1'
[libraries]
realm-gradle-plugin = { module = "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "realm" }

Project-level build.gradle.kts:
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.realm.gradle.plugin) // Can't be migrated yet https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/device-sdks/sdk/java/install/#project-gradle-configuration
    }
}

Module-level (e.g. app) build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    id("realm-android")
}


For Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1, and Realm Java SDK:
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
realmPlugin= "10.18.0"

[libraries]
io-realm-gradle-plugin = { module = "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "realmPlugin" }

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.io.realm.gradle.plugin)
    }
}

module/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

apply(plugin="realm-android")

